# Which classic serif font is this one?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, serif

[image]

Hello! I'm looking for the name this font! Any ideas?

Comment: I know it's not the [Didot](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/didot/) but they actually really look alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image][image]Very confident it is Clarendon Light based on the width of the letters.

[Clarendon Light](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/clarendon/)

Comment: R does not match. The middle horizontal bar has irregular thickness in the font in question, while bar in your variant is equal in the whole horizontal bar. We dont have sufficient amount of letters to define the exact font. I could write 20 similar variants to the font in question. Upper diagonal part of K is too thick comparing to the K in question.

Comment: It is an embossing, so thickness is slightly subjective.  However, a quick look at Century tells me there is an extreme difference in the width.  The example clearly shows a slightly extended width font, in which Clarendon fits the bill.  Closest one yet to hit the "essence" in my opinion :)

Comment: @ilan Ok, no worries.  Just what I would recommend in contrast to the other suggestions.

Comment: While you are in the parking lot of the ballpark, it's definitely not Clarendon--which has a much more even weight between thin and thick strokes.

Answer (score 6):

[image]Probably [Century font family](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/century/std-light/glyphs.html) or a similar one.

Also looks like Corona font (http://cdnimg.fonts.net/CatalogImages/23/44530.png)

Comment: Seems too tall to my eye but the tracking is making it look wider... close though!

Comment: @Emilie there are 20 variants, as you can see, I did not edited the post to add pictures - because we don't have sufficient amount of glyphs. But letter "K" :) is so elegant...

Comment: Probably a small cap version.

Comment: Ionic is my closest guess but not quite http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/ionic-mt/